# My button is not interactive but I added the java? This is on ANDROID STUDIO

Tags: android

I am trying to have my button show the text assigned with the checkbox the user chooses. Before I came here to ask I posted this problem on Udacity
disscusion forums, no answers yet. I also asked people in general if they knew anything. Then I came here hoping somebody could help me.

```
public void finishOff(View v){

    if(dogPower){
        TextView txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.first_graph);
        txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    if(chocoPower){
        TextView tvw=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.sec_graph);
        tvw.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

If you think I did not call the method in my Button, I did but just in case
I put a screenshot of my xml for the Button.

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/finish"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:onClick="finishOff"
```

My Checkboxes:

```
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/shih_Tzu_checkbox"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/check_shih_tzu"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light"/>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/choc_lab_checkbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/chocolate_lab"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light"/>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/gold_lab_checkbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/golden_lab"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light"/>
```

Comment: where is the checkbox? Please, post more code and your layout.

Comment: Can you add a log message to the _finishOff_ method to verify the method is actually being called? Where in your code are you setting the boolean value of _dogPower_ and _chocoPower_? Is it possible that these are both _false_ therefore no change is made? Can you click [edit] and add more context? Voting to close due to lack of context.

Comment: <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/shih_Tzu_checkbox"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/check_shih_tzu"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light"/>

Comment: <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/choc_lab_checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/chocolate_lab"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/gold_lab_checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/golden_lab"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light"/>

Comment: <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/malte_checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/malte"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/beagle_checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/beagle"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light"/>

Comment: These are the checkboxes. I will add it in my question in a sec.

Comment: Describe the conditions chocoPower and dogPower please.

Comment: And I still don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I still understand what are you trying to do. What are those two boolean values dogPower,chocoPower. Are those buttons or some variable you use for checking. If so have you initialized those variables or have you set those values based on checkbox